getting jit-lock to consider more context (seems error-prone in haskell-mode)
I'm writing Haskell code using haskell-mode.  Normally it does a good job of fontifying the buffer.  However, there is one particular construct it does not handle well.
If I have a Haskell function like this:
currIndex
  :: HasCallStack
  => Hose
  -> IO PoolIndex

Normally, currIndex will be in blue (haskell-definition-face).  However, occasionally as I scroll through the buffer, one of these function names will incorrectly be in black (default).  This seems to happen in a nondeterministic way as I view and edit the buffer over time.  Sometimes incorrect things will become correct, and something correct things will become incorrect.
My guess is that this is an artifact of how jit-lock-mode processes chunks of lines.  In particular, I suspect it's not considering that if it stops in an arbitrary place, it's possible that the following line could have affected the fontification.  (i. e. the :: on line 2 affects whether currIndex on line 1 should be in haskell-definition-face.)
I've read through the jit-lock customization group, and I also (very briefly) looked at jit-lock.el.  However, I haven't found any obvious parameters for how to get jit-lock to look at a larger range of lines than the range it is fontifying.  (In particular, I need it to consider at least 1 line following the range that is being fontified.)
I'm a little out of my depth.  Any suggestions on how I can make haskell-mode and jit-lock-mode play more nicely together?
I don't really care how efficient it is; I'm on a modern machine with 8 cores and 64 gigs of RAM, and I'm usually editing source files of less than a thousand lines.  So I don't mind if it fontifies way more than it needs to, more often than it needs to.  I just want it to be fontified correctly, all the time.
